# Issue applying pseudo active class to element object

Tags: html, css

I have a div that acts as a tile/box and when the div is hovered or active, the background-color should change. My hover is fine, but my active is having issues an not sure why. My code:

html:

```
<div class="swipeBoxes" ng-repeat="swipe in swipes">
    <a href="" ng-click="editSwipe(swipe)" >
        <div class="swipeBox col-md-12">
            <div class="col-md-12 claimObject">
                <span class="claimLine" style="width: 3px; position: absolute; top: 5px; left: 5px;">{{ $index + 1 }}.</span>
                <span class="claimedLeft">swipe date:</span>
                <span class="claimedRight">{{ swipe.date | date: 'MM/dd/yyyy'}}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 claimObject">
                <span class="claimedLeft">provider:</span
                ><span class="claimedRight">{{ swipe.merchant }}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 claimObject">
                <span class="claimedLeft">amount:</span>
                <span class="claimedRight">{{ swipe.amount | currency }}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Trying to apply active to the swipeBox class (no, it isn't the parent for the anchor, but should still work). The CSS:

```
.swipeBox:hover, .swipeBox:active {
    background-color: #efefef;
}
```

Comment: @steveax - thanks for that. Hadn't tried this before like this. That said, what have folks done to resolve this where they need a div to have an active state?

Comment: What is the actual issue you are facing?
you are missing a 'dot' before 'swipeBox:hover'

Comment: Couldn't you just do `a:hover .swipeBox, a:active .swipeBox` (e.g. https://jsfiddle.net/jmarikle/f7mbkzd3/) or is that not the effect you're going for?  What exactly triggers the "active" state of your div.  Normally that doesn't happen for non-interactive elements.